# Why no standard-defined literal suffix for std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, user-defined-literals, c++14

A quick question: why doesn't C++11 offer a "user-" (really, standard library) defined literal for creating a `std::string`, such as

```
auto str = "hello world"s; // str is a std::string
```

Like C++, Objective-C supports both C-style strings and a more user-friendly library type `NSString`; however, unlike C++, nobody ever gets confused between the two, because it's trivial to create an `NSString` by prefixing a string literal with `@`. In fact, it's rare to see Objective-C code where a literal *doesn't* have the `@` prefix. Everybody just knows that's the way to do it, uses `NSString` and gets on with it.

C++11 user-defined literals would allow this, and in fact the UDL section on Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ uses exactly this example. Furthermore, UDLs without a leading underscore are reserved, so there would be no problem in allowing a plain `s` as above -- there's no possibility of it clashing with anything else.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems like this would be a very valuable and risk-free addition to the language, so does anybody know why C++11 doesn't offer it? Is it likely to appear in C++14?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

User-defined literals were new enough in C++11 that this wasn't included, but it is in C++14( in §21.7, in case anybody cares). And yes, it uses `s` as the suffix. The precise result type depends on the type of the string literal itself -- a "narrow" literal gives an `std::string`, a u16 literal gives a `u16string`, and a u32 literal gives a `u32string`. Oh, and yeah, if you insist on using a wide string literal it'll produce a `wstring`.

Note that the `s` suffix is also used to mean seconds (defined in `<chrono>`) but there's no real conflict between the two--`s` on a string literal means a string, and `s` on a number means seconds.

Comment: Well, there we go, a perfect answer in a matter of seconds, +1 (or more if I could). Strange that it wasn't part of the original UDL proposal, but there we go. I look forward to finally (hopefully) losing the curse of `char*` in C++14!

Comment: I would love to use this especially in combination with `auto`

Comment: @Excelcius: More important than with `auto` (at least IMO) is simply in expressions, such as adding strings together: `"A"s + "B"s`, for example.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: it looks to me like you are adding As and Bs :p

Comment: @MatthieuM.: and so I am (or least an A and a B).